# C++ Getting class/struct address in 8086

Tags: c++, assembly, cpu-registers, x86-16

I am trying to figure out how to get and store the address of a struct/class object in a 8086 architecture using Borland C++ Compiler.

Trying to do something like:

```
    struct Data{
         unsigned int a; // +0
         unsigned int b; // +2
         unsigned int c; // +4
         unsigned int d; // +6
    };

    int main() {
    Data* r = new Data();
    unsigned int temp; 
    asm {
      mov temp, bx
      mov bx, r
      mov bx[0], ax
      mov bx[4], cx
      mov bx[6], dx 
    }
    r->b = temp;
    // write registry values on screen and check with actual register values
    }
```

Now i tried a lot of ways of making the:

```
mov bx, r
```

Line work (using FP_OFF and FP_SEG) but with no success.
Atm im just moving the register values in temporary variables and then writing those variables into the struct like:

```
    struct Data{
         unsigned int a; // +0
         unsigned int b; // +2
         unsigned int c; // +4
         unsigned int d; // +6
    };

    int main() {
    Data* r = new Data();
    unsigned int ta, tb, tc, td; 
    asm {
      mov ta, ax
      mov tb, bx
      mov tc, cx
      mov td, dx
    }
    r->a = ax;
    r->b = bx;
    r->c = cx;
    r->d = dx;
    // write registry values on screen and check with actual register values
    }
```

But I would like to know how would I do it using the address of the object so I could reduce the amount of variables used and reduce code clutter.

**UPDATE**

I think i found the correct way:

```
    struct Data{
         unsigned int a; // +0
         unsigned int b; // +2
         unsigned int c; // +4
         unsigned int d; // +6
    };

    int main() {
    Data* r = new Data();
    unsigned int dataOff, dataSeg;
    dataOff = FP_OFF(r);
    dataSeg = FP_SEG(r);
    asm {
      push ds
      push bx

      mov bx, dataOff
      mov ds, dataSeg

      mov bx[0], ax
      mov bx[4], cx
      mov bx[6], dx 
      pop WORD PTR bx[2]
      pop ds
    }
    // write registry values on screen and check with actual register values
    }
```

I forgot to change the DS (data segment) register to match the segment value of the object memory location.
Would be nice to have someone verify this is the correct way.

Comment: Which model are you using?

Comment: You could use TASM for the assembly part. It has powerful STRUCT definitiion that calculates the offset for you.

Comment: I am using the HUGE memory model.

Comment: in c99 the address of the struct is the address of its first member if that helps:)

Comment: Yes i knew that, i put the offsets in the comments next to struct members.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think you could reduce the code straightforwardly enough (unfortunately I dont have a C++ compiler on this computer yet so I have to wait until I get back home to my dev machine), however `mov r->a, ax` should work to allow you to put the data straight into the struct location you want to use

Comment: I tried using:

      mov r->a, ax

However i get a syntax error with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify structure name and field like this:

```
mov [bx+Data.a], ax
mov [bx+Data.c], cx
mov [bx+Data.d], dx
```